# How to center text in a div, which contains an Icon

Tags: html, css

I got the following question, with a pic to illustrate:

[image: pic]

I got a container, containing an icon and text. The Icon is always on the left, there can be more icons which are all fixed on the left. Now I want the text to be in the centre of the container. If the text gets too long, it should NOT overlap the icons, but it should expand to the right instead.

If the text is too long to fit in the container next to the icon, finally I just ellipse it.

But how do I do this? Is there a css solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: re-edit the question and post some code so that it would be easy to provide solution

Comment: Guys, if you downvote an answer, do it because the answer is bad, not the question. And please leave a comment to let author (and everyone) know why it's bad. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Answer (score 1):

You can have the text taking the entire width of the container parent, but having left and right padding in a way that it will have enough space for the icon.

Then you can have the icon overlaying on top of the textbox.

The text box can align text in the center and clip text if overflow.

I made a simple pen to illustrate the idea. I hope this help

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/thanhng/pen/jpgmRe)

Here's the code.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-map"></i>
  <div class="textbox"><span class='centerized-text'>This is a centered text and it is very long</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  background-color: #FAFBFD;
  width: 15rem;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
i {
  color: teal;
  position: absolute;
}
.textbox {
  padding: 0 1.3rem;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;

}
body {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #dedede;
}
```

(The style for body is just for your visual pleasure)

Comment: Your answer would be better with a corresponding example or code. Currently, this is categorized as a comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a code

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

#icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#text {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="icon"></span>
  <span id="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

To have text centered in the block

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="icon"></span>
  <span id="text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is not exactly the solution for my Problem, as the text is not centered in the whole container. Its closer to the right edge, because of the icon. I want the text to be in the center of the WHOLE container. The problem is, if the text gets too long it should not overlap the icon.

Answer (score -2):

In a container use, two `span tag` and First span will contain your `image tab` and another has text in it.

You can use `align-text-center` to center your text.